# How to aggregate logs by field and then by bin in AWS CloudWatch Insights?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm trying to do a query that will first aggregate by field count and after by `bin(1h)` for example I would like to get the result like:

```
# Date                     Field Count
1 2019-01-01T10:00:00.000Z A     123
2 2019-01-01T11:00:00.000Z A     456
3 2019-01-01T10:00:00.000Z B     567
4 2019-01-01T11:00:00.000Z B     789
```

Not sure if it's possible though, the query should be something like:

```
fields Field
| stats count() by Field by bin(1h)
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
fields Field | stats count() by Field, bin(1h)
```

Comment: Hi, this solution does not allow to see line charts. My use case is to create a graph  that displays one line per TaskId with average cpu and memory data.
Something like this but it doesn't work :  
stats avg(MemoryUtilized) by TaskId, bin(5m)
Do you think it's doable ?
Thanks

Comment: Hey @HugoMallet, were you able to figure it out ?

Comment: No, I haven't ☹️

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a line chart, you can do it by separately counting each value that your field could take.

```
fields
    Field = 'A' as is_A,
    Field = 'B' as is_B
| stats sum(is_A) as A, sum(is_B) as B by bin(1hour)
```

This solution requires your query to include a string literal of each value (`'A'` and `'B'` in OP's example). It works as long as you know what those possible values are.

This might be what [Hugo Mallet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2440064/hugo-mallet) was looking for, except the `avg()` function won't work here so he'd have to calculate the average by dividing by a total

Answer (score 1):

Not able to group by a certain field and create visualizations.

```
fields Field
| stats count() by Field, bin(1h)
```

Keep getting this message

```
No visualization available. Try this to get started:
stats count() by bin(30s)
```

Comment: I'm also struggling with this, there's an advertised Stack Chart option, but a field + bin() are not compatible with it.